# PL/SQL recursive function return no value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got the error message while running Oracle PL/SQL recursive function

> function returned without value

Anyone knows what might be the issue?

Here's my function

```
FUNCTION cgic (cnt IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      n_inv_code   VARCHAR2 (20);
      t_ic_chk                           NUMBER;
   BEGIN
                  SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('X', 10)
      INTO n_inv_code
      FROM DUAL;

                  select count(*) into t_ic_chk from inv_code where inv_code = n_inv_code and rownum = 1;

      IF t_ic_chk = 1
      THEN
                    n_inv_code := cgic(cnt);
      ELSE
                    IF t_ic_chk = 0
                                THEN
                      RETURN n_inv_code;
                                END IF;
      END IF;
   END cgic;
```

Comment: What is going to happen when `t_ic_chk <> 1` ?

Comment: with rownum = 1, should not it always be 0 or 1?

Comment: What's the full ORA code error, and did you get it during Compile time, or runtime ?

Comment: ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value
ORA-06512: at "ESAPP.EXPORT", line 24
ORA-06512: at "ESAPP.EXPORT", line 426
ORA-06512: at line 1  <br> The error is thrown at runtime when a shell script calling a SP which called this function. Line 24 is the declaration of the SP and line 426 is the function call.

Comment: Your function has an execution path that doesn't end to a `return` statement. It's simply a bug in the function implementation. Unfortunately the compiler won't catch the bug for your (at least in 11gR2)  but the exception takes place in runtime only.

Comment: @user272735 - the compiler catches it but gives a `PLW-05005` warning rather than failing compilation.

Comment: @elsiehsu - this kind of structural issue can be easier to spot if you lay out your code neatly.

Answer (score 3):

In the event `t_ic_chk = 1`

you assign the value of the recursive function back to the variable: `n_inv_code`

however, you don't DO anything with it.
You probably want to return it.

I would recommend this code in your final section:

```
  IF t_ic_chk = 1
  THEN
                n_inv_code := cgic(cnt);
  END IF;
  RETURN n_inv_code;
END cgic;
```

That's all you need:

1) if you find a row, recurse back in until you can't find one, and return that value.
2) if you can't find a row, return that value back.
3) in the event you found a row, just hand-shake the value returned back to whoever called you.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot the return part here and expecting the recursive call return it .... Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The code starting with `IF t_ic_chk = 1` might be replaced with

```
CASE t_ic_chk
  WHEN 0 THEN RETURN n_inv_code;
  WHEN 1 THEN RETURN cgic(cnt);
  ELSE RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202, 'Unexpected t_ic_chk value=' || t_ic_chk);
END;
```

Done this way your function will either return an expected value or will raise an exception if it doesn't know what to do with the value it finds in t_ic_chk.

I do wonder why you're passing in the `cnt` parameter as it's never used in the procedure, except to pass it on in the recursive call.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually calling this function in a loop within a SP and doesn't want to exit when there is an exception.